# Detecting changes for 'docker-compose build' in ansible

Tags: docker, ansible, docker-compose

Let's say an ansible task performs `docker-compose pull`, and reports the result like this:

```
changed_when: "'... pull complete' in result.stderr |default('')"
```

That works because stdout shows "... pull complete" only the first time - if the image exists then it does not.

*Is there an similar way to deal with `docker-compose build`?*

```
- name: foo
  shell: "docker-compose build"
  args:
    chdir: "{{FOO_PATH}}"
  register: result
  changed_when: "'???' in result.stderr |default('')"    # <----------- ?
```

Whether I'm building an image for the first time, or it already exists, stdout always shows me:

> Successfully built fbd38aa5b45a
>   Successfully tagged foo/bar:latest

I also checked "$?" which is always `0`. Is there a way to detect whether the build occurred or not?

Comment: Any particular reason not to use the [`docker_compose` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_compose_module.html) ? It should be able to manage all this in a single task and manage idempotency for you.

Comment: @Zeitounator I'm gonna try your way. Thanks for the tip.